# Suppose S = {1,2,3,4}. How many diﬀerent subsets are there of S?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given: $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

How many subsets of $S$ are there which have more than one element?

I know that there are $2^7=128$ subsets of $S$.  Now, if we take into account the empty set, then shouldn't there be $2^7-8=120$ subsets of $S$ that have more than one element?  I'm trying to find out if my thinking is correct.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: Indeed your thinking is exactly right: number of subsets with more than 1 element equals total number of subsets minus number of subsets with at most 1 element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

community wiki answer so this question can be closed

Your solution is correct.